# How to check expiry date of pfx file?

Tags: visual-studio, pfx

How should I check the expiry date of `pfx` file? Can this be done in Visual Studio?

Comment: A pfx file does not expire, only the certificate(s) it contains. Therefore it may happen that an pfx file contains both a valid and an outdated certificate.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/580697/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-pfx-file-on-windows), you can review the information of the certificate before import it using:

```
certutil -dump YourCertificate.pfx
```

If you want to run this from Visual Studio you can do this:

1. Go to *Tools* > *External Tools* > *Add*
2. Set the required info: **Name**=`CertUtil` **Command**=`C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe` **Arguments**=`-p YourPass -dump $(ItemPath)`. Check *Use output window*.

With this you can execute the command for the selected file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you Rolo for your help and time.